# nasm/gcc issue on 64-bit Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, gcc, nasm

I was reading [this](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) article,
and at one point it gives me this nasm program:

```
; tiny.asm
BITS 32
GLOBAL main
SECTION .text
main:
              mov     eax, 42
              ret
```

And tells me to run the following commands:

```
$ nasm -f elf tiny.asm
$ gcc -Wall -s tiny.o
```

I got the following error:

```
ld: warning: option -s is obsolete and being ignored
ld: warning: ignoring file tiny.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I ventured a guess at what might be the problem, and changed the BITS line to read:

```
 BITS 64
```

But then when I run `nasm -f elf tiny.asm` I get:

```
tiny.asm:2: error: `64' is not a valid segment size; must be 16 or 32
```

How do I modify the code to work on my machine?

Edit:

I took Alex's advice from the comments and downloaded a newer version. However,

```
./nasm-2.09.10/nasm -f elf tiny.asm
```

complains

```
tiny.asm:2: error: elf32 output format does not support 64-bit code
```

On the other hand,

```
./nasm-2.09.10/nasm -f elf64 tiny.asm
gcc -Wall -s tiny.o
```

complains

```
ld: warning: ignoring file tiny.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: @Alex elf64 gave me "unrecognized output format". As for the version, nasm -v gave me "NASM version 0.98.40 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 11) compiled on Nov  3 2011" 0.98 looks like it might be an old version but it was compiled in 2011 so it can't be that old right? Why would Apple ship outdated software? A default assembler that can't assemble 64-bit code on a 64-bit platform?

Comment: Yours is horribly outdated. Mine prints "NASM version 2.09.10 compiled on Jul 15 2011". The newer version is [here](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.09.10/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are OS X-specific adjustments you have to make in order for your example to work:
The main method is prepended with a _ by the OS X linker:

```
; tiny.asm
BITS 32
GLOBAL _main
SECTION .text
_main:
    mov     eax, 42
    ret
```

The second is that you have to use the mach file format:

```
nasm -f macho tiny.asm
```

Now you can link it (using -m32 to indicate a 32 bit object file):

```
gcc -m32 tiny.o
```

Comment: **For 64-bit code, use `-fmacho64`**.  Also, you don't need `bits 32`, and I'd recommend avoiding it.  You *want* an error message if you try to assemble 32-bit source code into a 64-bit object file or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are still using the 32-bit version.  If you `nasm -hf` it should list `macho64`.  If not you'll need to update again.

You could try in the console `brew update` .  If this performs an update then `brew search nasm` where it should bring up `nasm`.  Then simply `brew install nasm`.  This should install nasm to your computer.  Be sure sure to look out for the location where it was installed.  Mine was installed at `/usr/local/cellar/nasm/2.11.02/bin/` .  Then by typing `nasm -hf` it should bring up a list of available formats which you should see `macho64` available.