# Mac OS X 32-bit nasm assembly program using main and scanf/printf?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, assembly, nasm

I have spent the entire day trying to get some simple programs compiled but so far very little luck. What I want to do is to compile and run programs written in nasm assembly.

I have upgraded to latest nasm (v2.10.09). So let me just jump into code since I do not know a lot about these things yet. Here is a chunk of assembly code that runs on linux using `elf` format and linked witch gcc (comments are my understanding of what is going on):

```
bits 32
extern printf
global main

section .data
    message db "Hello world!", 10, 0

section .text
main:
    pushad                      ;push all registers on stack
    push dword message                  ;push the string on stack
    call printf                 ;call printf
    add esp, 4                  ;clear stack
    popad                       ;pop all registers back
    ret                     ;return to whoever called me
```

Nothing too big. However how the hell am I supposed to get this to work on OS X? I cant even get it to compile/link in any way. If it compiles I cant link it (something about i386 and x86 which cant be linked together (I understand that but how to fix it?)). I have tried a dozen ways with no luck.

Further more how can I `printf` and `scanf` on OS X assembly?

Here is another futile attempt of a `scanf` and `printf` the value back (this one actually compiles and links - and even runs!):

```
[bits 32] ; why the []?

section .data
    input_string    db  "Enter limit: %d", 0
    output_string   db  "Value %d", 10, 0
    counter         dd  10
    limit           dd  0

;nasm -f macho -o test.o test.asm 
;ld -lc -o test -arch i386 test.o -macosx_version_min 10.7

section .text

global start
extern _printf
extern _scanf
extern _exit

start:
    push ebp                ;push stack base
    mov ebp, esp            ;base is now current top
    and esp, 0xFFFFFFF0     ;align the stack - WHY? I just googled this?

    sub esp, 16             ;16 bytes for variables - 16 to keep the stack "aligned". WHY?

    mov dword[esp], input_string         ;ordinary push just isint good nuff for mac... WHY?
    mov dword[esp + 4], limit
    call _scanf                          ;does scan something but doesnt print the message, it just scans and then prints the message

    mov eax, [limit]                      ;since i cant push this lets put it in eax first


    mov dword[esp + 8], output_string     ;push the output string. WHY again MOV?
    mov dword[esp + 12], eax              ;and the previusly "scanned" variable
    call _printf                          ;print it out

    mov dword[esp], 0       ;return value
    call _exit              ;return
```

Compiled it with: `nasm -f macho -o test.o test.asm` and linked it with `d -lc -o test -arch i386 test.o -macosx_version_min 10.7`. Doesnt work properly. On linux its super easy to to this scanf and printf thingie. What's up here? Can it be done simpler?

I do not want to add more stuff to this question since people sometimes see a big question and thing "meh, too long, wont read". But if anyone requests more info I'll do my best.

Please help me since I cant figure it out.

**EDIT**
The first one compiles using `nasm -f macho -o out.o test.asm` but doest link using `gcc -o test out.o` or by using `ld -lc -o test -arch i386 out.o -macosx_version_min 10.7` and appending flat `-arch i386` doesnt solve it either. I would love if I could write that "linux like" assembly since I do not have to worry about stack alignment and stuff like that.
gcc error says:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file out.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): out.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

and ld error is as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "printf", referenced from:
      main in out.o
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Please help.

Comment: What are the exact error messages are you seeing?  Does nasm run to completion, or does it generate an error?  Try *file test.o* to find the file format of the generated object file.  I'm not sure, but it looks like nasm generates 32-bit object files, but all the libraries are 64-bit these days.  Just a guess.

Comment: Have edited the question accordingly. See question. Thanks.

Comment: I think this previously asked question will address *most* of your issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308806/nasm-gcc-issue-on-64-bit-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: I changed the labels so they include an underscore (_) and it did compile and link. But the program crashes saying it's a Segmentation Fault: 11. It disappears if I comment out the printf line. What's up with that and how to fix it?

But we are getting closer which means thanks a lot! I just need printf and scanf to work.

Comment: Parameters to `_printf` should be at `[esp]` and `[esp + 4]` I think.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're asking a lot of questions about your code, and you really don't understand the assembly code that's there.

Firstly, because of the way you're writing your code, the `main` routine is going to be the entry point of a C style program. Because of the way that mac os x linkages work; you're going to have to name it `_main` to match the name of the symbol being looked for by the linker as the default program entry point when it pulls in `/usr/lib/crt1.o` when producing the executable (if you do an nm of the file you'll see an entry like: `U _main`. Similarly, all the library routines start with a leading underscore so you have to use that prefix if you want to use them.

Secondly, the MAC OS calling convention requires a 16 byte alignment of the stack for all `call`s which means that you have to ensure that the stack pointer is aligned relevantly at each point. At the entry point of the main routine you already know that you're misaligned due to the return address being stored in the stack for returning from main. This means that if you want to make even a single call you're going to have to move the stack down by at least 12 bytes to make the call.

Armed with that piece of information, we're going to omit futzing around with the `ebp`, and just use esp exclusively for the purposes of the code.

This is assuming a prolog of:

```
bits 32
extern _printf
global _main

section .data
    message db "Hello world!", 10, 0

section .text
_main:
```

On entry into `_main`, realign the stack:

```
sub esp, 12
```

Next we store the address of the message into the address pointed to by esp:

```
mov dword[esp], message
```

Then we call printf:

```
call _printf
```

Then we restore the stack:

```
add esp, 12
```

Set the return code for `main`, and return:

```
mov eax, 0
ret
```

The ABI for MAC OS X uses `eax` as the return code for the routine as long as it fits in a register. Once you've compiled and linked the code:

```
nasm -f macho -o test.o test.asm 
ld -o test -arch i386 test.o -macosx_version_min 10.7 -lc /usr/lib/crt1.o
```

It runs and prints the message, exiting with a `0`.

Next we're going to play around with your scanning and printing example.

Firstly, scanf only scans, you can't have a prompt in there; it's simply not going to work, so you have to split the prompt from the scanning. We've already shown you how to do the print, and now what we need to show is the scanf.

Set up the variables in the data section:

```
scan_string     db  "%d", 0
limit           dd  0
```

First store the address of `scan_string` in `esp`, and then store the *address* of limit in `esp + 4`, then call scanf:

```
mov dword[esp], scan_string
mov dword[esp + 4], limit
call _scanf
```

We now should have the value that we scanned stored in the limit memory location.

Next to print this message:

```
output_string   db  "Value %d", 10, 0
```

Next we put the address of output_string on the stack:

```
mov dword[esp], output_string
```

Read the value of the limit address into the eax register and put it into `esp + 4` - i.e. the second parameter for printf:

```
mov eax, [limit]
mov dword[esp + 4], eax
call _printf
```

Next, we're calling exit, so we have to store the exit code in the stack and invoke the `_exit` function - this is different from the simple print variant as we're actually invoking exit, rather than simply returning.

```
mov dword[esp], 0
call _exit
```

As for some of the questions:

Why the alignment?

> Because that's how Mac OS X does it

Why isn't push good enough?

> It is, but we aligned the stack at the start of the routine and an aligned stack is a functioning stack, by pushing and popping you're messing with the alignment. This is one of the purposes behind using the `ebp` register rather than the `esp` register.

If we were to use the `ebp` register, the function prolog would look like:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 8 ; in this case to obtain alignment
```

and the function epilog would look like:

```
add esp, 8
pop ebp
```

You can put in symmetric pusha/popa calls in there as well, but if you're not using the registers, why complicate the stack.

A better overview of the 32bit function calling mechanism is on the [OS X Developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002492-SW4), The ABI function call guide gives the far more detail on the hows of parameter passing and returning. It's based on the [AT&T System V ABI for the i386](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), with a few listed differences:

- Different rules for returning structures
- The stack is 16-byte aligned at the point of function calls
- Large data types (larger than 4 bytes) are kept at their natural alignment
- Most floating-point operations are carried out using the SSE unit instead of the x87 FPU, except when operating on long double values. (The IA-32 environment defaults to 64-bit internal precision for the x87 FPU.)

Comment: I am having problems with linking the first program you wrote. Haven't got to the second one yet since I want the first one to work. I Basically copied and pasted your program line by line and compiled and tried to link with the specified commands. However `ld` pops up something like:
`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "start", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`
What to do?

Comment: My bad, I was using mavericks, and it took main when it couldn't find start. I've updated the link line so it should work now,

Comment: If you don't want to explicitly use `crt1.o`, you can pass in `-e_main` which skips the main startup, but in that case you really have to call `exit` at the end, as you can't just fall off the end of the program

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver! I still do have a question though. Why `sub esp, 12`? Shouldnt the stack be 16 bytes aligned? Or how does this work? And what happened to the `and esp, 0xFFFFFFF0` which is also there to align the stack? Isin't it? :)

Comment: Well firstly, there are 4 bytes pushed onto the stack as a result of the call - the return address. The ABI guarantees that the alignment is to 16 bytes, which means that we have 12 bytes to offset before we can call any subroutines (otherwise you hit the misaligned stack trap/handler), so we just reduce it by 12 bytes to make the alignment work out. We don't perform the `and` because it's not needed as we know all the preconditions of entry into the routine

Comment: Now if you were calling printf with, say, 4 parameters, then you would have to offset the stack by an even larger amount as you would otherwise overwrite the stack with the parameters that you were passing in. In order to support this you simply subtract enough 16s from the stack pointer until it can cope with all the values that you're passing in while retaining alignment. As an aside, the typical function prolog does a `push ebp`, which would gobble up another 4 bytes which you would have to compensate for in your `sub esp` call.

Comment: +1 Very well written answer. I really wonder how this "small network monitoring company" of yours leverages your obvious reversing skills :D....

Comment: you = god. Totally saved me.

Comment: I was able to get it linked with `ld -o test -e _main -arch i386 test.o -macosx_version_min 10.7 -lc -no_pie` (it couldn't find `/usr/lib/crt1.o`, though I did eventually locate it with `locate crt1.o`, it's in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o`) There's definitely a lot going on that I don't understand, but I've got a working example in a gist, including the invocation (https://gist.github.com/JoshCheek/b978b95c5990cde910815ccf172be8c4) Anyway, awesome comment, ty!!

Comment: It turns up in `/usr/lib/crt1.o` if you install the command line tools (`xcode-select --install`)